# Почему "сколько их" надо выделять запятыми?

Tags: запятая

Почему в данном предложении "сколько их" надо выделять запятыми: "Я не знаю, сколько их, монументов славы и победы в нашей стране и за ее пределами".

Comment: @Dima, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы и после слова ПОБЕДЫ поставила: "Я не знаю, сколько их, монументов славы и победы, в нашей стране и за ее пределами". Если убрать уточняющее приложение, останется: "Я не знаю, сколько их в нашей стране и за ее пределами". Хотя и то возможно, но громоздко.

Answer (score 0):

"Монументов славы и победы в нашей стране и за ее пределами" - приложение, стоит после определяемого слова "их", тем более что определяемое слово выражено личным местоимением, поэтому нужна запятая, но лучше поставить тире после "их", так как приложение носит пояснительный характер и стоит в конце предложения

Comment: Приложение? Наверное, пояснение. 

===

Сколько их (кого именно "их"?) -- монументов...

Comment: Это называется приложение, носящее пояснительный характер (см. Розенталя)